# Grunt Workflow Static Assets Fingerprint

Tags: gruntjs, fingerprint

I'm writing a small Mobile Web Application to get started. 
So far so good, however I'm considering optimizing performance server-side.

After read about server compression and caching, I'd like to implement fingerprint of static resources. Basically, both W3 Mobile Web Application best practices and Google performance guide recommends it.

I'm using Grunt as the main tool to switch from development to production. 
Found that Grunt got two plugins that can help me achieve that :

- https://github.com/testdouble/grunt-asset-fingerprint
- https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-fingerprint

However, I'm not sure how to update the html file to update link matching updated fingerprinted assets. Should i use some template variables ? I'm not a Grunt expert, use it only a few times for simple task so that might be the template system I have to dive in.

Anyway thanks by advance

Comment: Probably the most common method is to use [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin). If you can provide some more details about your code and project structure it would be helpful for providing a more specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too comfortable writing your own grunt tasks and would like to have asset fingerprinting as well as a ton of other features I suggest you look into Yeoman

http://yeoman.io

It'll set you up with a template for your webapp that just works. I've started using this quite a lot.

Comment: They use grunt-usemin I believe.